# Using ggplot, how can I add a point at a time in a loop and then connect them all by a line after the loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, point

I am going dealing with a lot of data and I was thinking of plotting one part of the data at a time using a loop.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
Department  Period  Sales
1005    1   3354.256
1005    1   5587.164
1005    2   3946.055
1005    2   5739.555
1005    3   3990.139
1005    3   6208.411
1005    4   3887.84
1005    4   6397.811
1008    1   4014.629
1008    1   5370.781
1008    2   4311.249
1008    2   5403.442
1008    3   4028.125
1008    3   6660.305
1008    4   4564.816
```

My initial idea was to plot one point at a time and then connect the points with a line after exiting the loop.

```
gp <- ggplot()

for (i in 1:4) {
  dat <- qdat[qdat$Period == i,]
  gp <- gp + stat_summary(data = dat , aes(x=Period , y=Sales), geom="point", fun.y="sum")
  print(gp)
}

final_plot <- gp + geom_line()
```

However, I only get the points, but am not able to generate any lines connecting the points.

Ideally, I would also like to know if it's possible to plot different line segments at a time to make one continuous line using a loop.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Abandon this idea. Generate all your data and plot in the end, in particular if you want to use ggplot2.

Comment: Are you generating these for an animation? Do you want to save intermediate plots?

Comment: No, I don't need the intermediate plots

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, using `ggplot` you should not add points one by one to the plot. It is easy to plot what you want in one step. I assume (tell me when I'm wrong) that you want to have Period on the x-axis and the sum over all sales belonging to that period on the y-asix. This can be done as follows.

First, I use `aggregate()` to sum up the sales per period:

```
plot.data <- aggregate(Sales~Period,data=qdat,FUN=sum)
```

With this data set, the plot can be done in a single line:

```
ggplot(plot.data,aes(x=Period,y=Sales)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Note that I use `geom_point()` **and** `geom_line()` in order to get points connected by a line. Using the data sample you gave, I get the following picture:

[image]